# Multi-peak fitting in Java with a gaussian and lorentzian function

Tags: java, curve-fitting

I'm writing a program in Java for handling some experimental data. I need to fit a function ( using a gaussian and a lorentzian ) to this data, then get the parameters of the peaks - their  FWHM ( Full Width at Half Maximum ), height, position, intensity ( area under ). Is there a free library which I can use for this? Or could I, for instance, somehow use gnuplot for this? I wish to avoid writing it all from scratch, if possible.

Ps. I've tagged this post as curve-fitting, because I couldn't find better tags, and I can't make new ones.

Answer (score 1):

You may look at libfityk, a part of [**fityk**](http://fityk.nieto.pl) (source code [at GitHub](https://github.com/wojdyr/fityk)). Disclaimer: I'm the author. Fityk is a program for (multi) peak fitting and more generally curve fitting and xy data analysis. License: GPL.

You can fit Gaussian, Lorentzian and many similar functions (Voigt, Pseudo-Voigt, Pearson7, split-Gaussian, split-Lorentzian, etc).

Libfityk has SWIG-generated bindings to a few languages, including Java. But I know of only one person who is using libfityk from Java, the library is primarily used from C++, Python and Lua.

The latest [fityk manual (at RTD)](https://fityk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) includes incomplete API docs.

I don't know what you are up to, but quite a few scriptable programs can do peak fitting, so maybe the quickest solution would be to pick and automate one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to have a look at peak-o-mat (http://lorentz.sf.net) which has a similar scope as fityk. peak-o-mat is both interactive program and fitting library based on scipy (python). The docs are incomplete but feel free to ask if you are missing something. Same disclaimer as above: I am the author.